# Python How Do I always select root folder no matter where my script is on linux?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

This is what I have working so far since I asked the question I solved it but just in case anyone else has the same question.

This is the working code.

```
import sys
import os
file_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/", topdown=True):
   for name in dirs:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))   
   for name in files:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))
      file_to_save = os.path.join(root, name)
      file_list.append(file_to_save)
```

This is the working attempts.

```
import sys
import os


for file_name in os.listdir('/'):
   print file_name
```

Another Non Working Attempt:

```
import sys
import os


for file_name in os.listdir('.'):
   print file_name
```

I'm making a file system reporter for a monitoring solution, but I ran in to something so simple but yet, I can't figure it out its one of those days. I'm going to use os.walk to walk through every directory on a server and I'm going to rebuild everything it finds into a list; each directory and sub directory and files will all be linked, this script will also accept commands to do things with the files. That way, we can manage server files remotely from a django web browser.

However, I can't seem to get it to select the root directory no matter where the script is placed. Obviously if I just place the minion on root it would work but I want it to be location irrelevant.

Comment: What's the problem? Just use "/".

Comment: but say my file is in django/files/scripts it will only go back one directory it will not select the root folder

Comment: ah ha moment thanks, I used / with finddir and not walk thanks man

Comment: You haven't posted any relevant code. Post what you've tried so far, and explain how it differs from your expected/desired result.

Comment: Point of clarification, '.' is the current working directory of the program, not the location of the program on disk.

Comment: Thanks, I tried looking for a good source of documentation on this but couldn't find any.

Comment: And to keep life complicted, on Windows, '/' is just the root of the current drive. If you have multiple drives, figuring out where all the files are is more complicated.

Comment: any ideas on ways to do windows? Figured id ask while you brought it up I was just going to focus on linux first and then go for windows once I prove the concept works and is secure.